# How to disable touchscreen on my Ubuntu 22 LTS version. It is booted alongside windows on my HP Pavilion 15T laptop

Tags: touchscreen

On running `xinput list` showing:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:16                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Disabling by input id =10 is not working . Please help.